# How long is an app awoken for after crossing a geofence?

Tags: ios, background, geofencing

When it comes to Background execution, Apple tends to impose very strict guidelines on developers, to save the phone's battery. The few activities that can relaunch your app *when it's not running* do so only for a very short time (10-30s depending on the activity). However, I can't find the duration for an app awoken by the user crossing a geofence. Does that mean it stays in the background indefinitely, only limited by memory pressure?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html):

> In iOS, regions associated with your app are tracked at all times, including when the app isn’t running. If a region boundary is crossed while an app isn’t running, that app is relaunched into the background to handle the event. Similarly, if the app is suspended when the event occurs, it’s woken up and given a short amount of time (**around 10 seconds**) to handle the event. When necessary, an app can request more background execution time using the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` method of the `UIApplication`class